# Hive GenericUDF Error - RuntimeException typeInfo cannot be null

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, runtimeexception

Running on Amazon EMR, Hive 0.11, I am trying to create a simple UDF with the GenericUDF class.  What I am trying to do with the UDF, is simply take in a value from a column, and print it back to the screen.  The whole point is to see if I can get this one working before building something more complicated.

I compile the jar, load into hive, and create a temporary function.

```
add jar ..../GenericTest.jar;
create temporary function gen_test as 'GenericTest';
```

When I run the function with the wrong number of arguments, I get the expected error:

```
SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:13 Arguments length mismatch 'gen_test': Wrong # of Args
```

However, when I pass it the right number of arguments, it fails immediately with the message:

```
FAILED: RuntimeException typeInfo cannot be null!
```

I have so far been unable to find the root of this problem.  The code of this UDF is below.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentLengthException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFUtils; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2. objectinspector.ObjectInspector;


public class GenericTest extends GenericUDF {

  private GenericUDFUtils.ReturnObjectInspectorResolver returnOIResolver;
  private ObjectInspector[] argumentOIs;

  public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments) throws UDFArgumentException {
     argumentOIs = arguments;
     if (arguments.length != 1) {
       throw new UDFArgumentLengthException("Wrong # of Args");
     }

        if (arguments[0].getCategory() != ObjectInspector.Category.PRIMITIVE)
        throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "Only primitive type arguments are accepted");

     returnOIResolver = new GenericUDFUtils.ReturnObjectInspectorResolver(true);

     return returnOIResolver.get();
  }

  public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
    Object retVal = returnOIResolver.convertIfNecessary(arguments[0].get(), argumentOIs[0]);
    return retVal;
  }

  public String getDisplayString(String[] children){
    String rt = "get Display String test";
    return rt;
  }

}
```

Comment: I have gotten this to run.  In initialize() I need something similar to `returnOIResolver.update(arguments[0]);` so that `return returnOIResolver.get();` will have something to return (the ObjectInspector for the return value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten this to run.

In initialize() I need something similar to `returnOIResolver.update(arguments[0]);` (shown in the first answer)  so that return `returnOIResolver.get();` will have something to return (the ObjectInspector for the return value).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try the basic one : you can use this one

```
package yarn;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentLengthException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;

public class GenericUDFNvl extends GenericUDF {
private GenericUDFUtils.ReturnObjectInspectorResolver returnOIResolver;
private ObjectInspector[] argumentOIs;
@Override
public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments)
throws UDFArgumentException {
 argumentOIs = arguments;
 if (arguments.length != 2) {
 throw new UDFArgumentLengthException(
 "The operator 'NVL' accepts 2 arguments.");
 }
 returnOIResolver = new GenericUDFUtils.ReturnObjectInspectorResolver(true);
 if (!(returnOIResolver.update(arguments[0]) && returnOIResolver
 .update(arguments[1]))) {
 throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(2,
 "The 1st and 2nd args of function NLV should have the same type, "
 + "but they are different: \"" + arguments[0].getTypeName()
 + "\" and \"" + arguments[1].getTypeName() + "\"");
 }
 return returnOIResolver.get();
 }
 @Override
 public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Object retVal = returnOIResolver.convertIfNecessary(arguments[0].get(),
            argumentOIs[0]);
            if (retVal == null ){
            retVal = returnOIResolver.convertIfNecessary(arguments[1].get(),
            argumentOIs[1]);
            }
            return retVal;


}
@Override

    public String getDisplayString(String[] children) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("if ");
        sb.append(children[0]);
        sb.append(" is null ");
        sb.append("returns");
        sb.append(children[1]);
        return sb.toString() ;
        }

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
}
```

You will have to pass 2 arguments what it does if your first argument is not null ,then it would print the first argument,if first argument is null then it would print the second argument

```
select nvl(movie_title,"test") from u_item_test1;
```

if movie_tittle is there then that movie_tittle ,if not then test would be printed

Comment: I can get this one to work.  Also was able to get mine to work if I run `returnOIResolver.update(arguments[0]);` in the initialize statement.